# Is it possible to close the print dialog?

Tags: javascript, browser, printing

By using `window.print()` we can trigger the print dialog to be opened.

Is there any way to close it?

It turns out that (at least on Chrome/Chromium), `location.reload()` does close it, but it reloads the page.

Is there any other friendlier way/API to close it?

Answer (score 0):

What about using `setTimeout`?

```
window.print(); //this triggers the print

setTimeout("closePrintView()", 3000); // delay required for IE to realise what's going on

window.onafterprint = closePrintView(); // this is the magic

// this function simply runs something you want it to do 
function closePrintView() {
  // do something
}
```

EDIT: There's also `onbeforeprint` if it's useful.

EDIT 2: It appears `onbeforeprint` fires **before** the dialog appears...

`onafterprint` is fired **just before** the dialog appears. So it's not possible to know if the document is printed or whether you've canceled the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var window = window.open();
window.print();
window.onfocus = function () {
    window.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check [**window.close**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close). This will close the current window.

```
var openPrint = window.print();
//Rest of code
 openPrint.close();
```

Comment: `window.print()` returns `undefined`. I want to close the print dialog, not the window.